# Rails 4 update_attributes with nested attributes not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to break up the registration process of my app into nice bite-size chunks.

So I'm posting forms via `Ajax` and just trying to update some of the models attributes that were available at that step of that process, basically meaning that they won't be valid at each save point.

As a result, I have been using `update_attribute` which works fine. However, one of my attributes is a `has_many` association and I'm struggling to get this working.

I have `Channel`model with `has_many :channel_tags`, and also `accepts_nested_attributes_for :channel_tags`. Saving and updating work fine when I use the update method but I cannot get it working with `update_attribute` or `update_attributes`.

As far as I can tell, I need to use `update_attributes`. I wanted to do something like:

```
@channel.update_attributes(channel_tags_attributes: params[:channel][:channel_tags_attributes])
```

But this doesn't create the new channel_tags. I have also tried with:

```
@channel.update_attributes(tag_params)
```

and:

```
params.require(:channel).permit(channel_tags_attributes: [ :id, :channel_id, :tag_id, :_destroy ]);
```

But again, it just doesn't seem to do anything.

When checking from the console, it appears that all of it's happening because that it's loading the `Channel` for the database and then the category.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried @channel.update_attributes(params[:channel][:channel_tags_attributes]) ?

Comment: We need more information. Can you show your form and/or the params that the form is posting?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name to permitted params method:-

```
def channel_params
    params.require(:channel).permit(channel_tags_attributes: [ :id, :channel_id, :tag_id, :_destroy ]);
end
```

and user this method in update attributes:-

```
def update
   @channel = Channel.find(params[:id])
   if @channel.update_attributes(channel_params)
       # add your code here
   end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

As you are trying to do it with nested attributes in rails 4 then your code should look like,

In tag model

```
has_many :channel_tags
accepts_nested_attributes_for :channel_tags, allow_destroy: true
```

Controller should look like

```
def update
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
  puts "==== #{tag_params.inspect} ===="
  puts "==== #{tag_params[:channel_tags].inspect} ===="
  if @tag.update!(tag_params)
    redirect_path
  end
end  
private
def tag_params
  params.require(:tag).permit(:name ,channel_tags_attributes: [:id, :channel_id, :tag_id, :_destroy])
end
```

While updating attributes please check the server logs as I have inspect the params which you try to update for the tag attribs.

.update_attributes will only when you want particular attributes. .update will use HASH in params which we are defining as strong params.